# $\sum\frac{(k!)^2}{2k!}$ serie converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the following series diverge or converge.

$\sum\frac{(k!)^2}{2k!}$

I decide to apply the powerful ratio test.

I did

$\frac{(k+1)!^2}{2(k+1)!}$

which then becomes

$\frac{(k+1)!(k+1)!}{(2k+2)!}$*$\frac{2k!}{(k!)(k!)}$

I get the

$k\rightarrow\infty$

$\frac{(k+1)(k+1)}{(2k+2)(2k+2)}$

=$\frac{1}{4}$

$\frac{1}{4}$<1

convergent?

Comment: Is the denominator intended to be $2(k!)$ or $(2k)!$?

Comment: let me see it is$(k!)^2$

Comment: I mean sorry it is $(2k)!$

Comment: Then the only error in everything is that you need the parentheses; $2k! = 2(k!)$, the factorial has higher precedence than multiplication.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez : please fix your _question_, don't just explain the mistake in a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're working with the series:

$$\sum\frac{(k!)^2}{(2k)!},$$ then you should be able to reduce the limit of the ratio to $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{(k+1)(k+1)}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}$$

The limit is still $\frac 14$, and so, yes, by the ratio test, we have that the series converges.

Comment: Oh yes I see because $(2k+2)(2k+1)$ are the only ones not cancel out in the $2k!$ factorial yes I think i made a typo

Comment: Yes, correct: the $(2k)!$ factorial;-)

Answer (score -3):

Fernando, I took a course on series last year; they taught us how to sum EVERYTHING. Even if a series is divergent, it still may be possible to sum! Sum is $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2 \pi}{9\sqrt{3}}$ . Remember, you must sum first, converge later.

Comment: But the task isn't to find the sum.

Comment: In my course on series, the task was ALWAYS to find the sum. I took a course on convergence the next semester and we learned a theorem to the effect that if the sum can be calculated, then the series is convergent.

Comment: but only a few series can sum like telescopic and geometric series unless you guys know more advanced series

Comment: No, every series can converge under a suitable interpretation, you must renormalize it. I think this is the answer your teacher is looking for. My prof once asked this as a trick question and many people said that some series do not converge, but there is always a renormailzation, you must search hard. For example $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n =-1/12$

Comment: @Peter : If you could sum everything, life would be wayyy easier in mathematics. I think you're just claiming you managed to learn a lot of stuff. :P